# How can I open all folds but the last one?

Tags: folding

I would like to open all folds in a buffer recursively apart from folds which contain just text and no further folds.

I know that `zO` opens all folds in a buffer but as explained this is different from what I would like to achieve. Furthermore it will also not help to set a specific fold level because the depth in the fold hierarchy is very different.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
zM
:folddoclosed if foldlevel('.') < foldlevel(line('.')+1) | exe 'norm! zo' | endif
```

Close all folds. Then, iterating over all lines in closed folds, check if the subsequent line has a greater foldlevel. If so, unfold the current line.

Comment: I tried to keybind the solution like this: `nnoremap ,z :%foldc!<CR>:folddoclosed if foldlevel('.') < foldlevel(line('.')+1) | exe 'norm! zo' | endif`. Unfortunately it does not work and I get some error messages E490 that there are no folds.

Comment: ok, I found out that I need to substitute `|` with `<bar>` in a vimrc file. Now it works

Comment: You can escape it too: `\|`.